# Copying PVectors in Processing

Tags: processing

```
PVector a = new PVector(1, 2);
PVector b = a;
PVector c = a.copy();
PVector d = a.get();
```

Not using .copy() method change one of my drawing.Is there any differences between b, c, d PVectors???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` and `copy()` are functionally identical -- each returns a **deep copy** of the PVector.

`PVector b = a;` creates a reference `b` that points to the same `PVector` object that `a` points to.

Therefore, there are differences between the `b`, and `c` & `d` PVectors.

Let's use your code and change the value of `a` after instantiating the other variables to see how they differ:

```
PVector a = new PVector(1, 2);

PVector b = a;
PVector c = a.copy();
PVector d = a.get();

a.x = 4;

println(a.x);
println(b.x);
println(c.x);
println(d.x);
```

Output:

```
4.0
4.0
1.0
1.0
```